# WP7 - How to access button properties in resources->style

Tags: windows-phone-7, resourcedictionary

I have this piece of code in my MainPage.xaml :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                                <Button x:Name="LoadMoreButton" Content="Load more data..." Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Click="LoadMoreData_Click" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

My question is how to access for example LoadMoreButton.Visibility property in MainPage.xaml.cs?

If I try to use LoadMoreButton.Visibility intelisense is not returning anything. I suppose that you cannot use resources elements like that but I hope so that some of you know solution of this "problem". Thank you in advance!

Comment: I know this isn't what you're looking for, but here's a great example and code for a list that automatically loads more when you're at the bottom. It works great, you can just place a TextBlock and an Indeterminate progress bar that says 'loading more...', which the user will see when they hit the bottom. http://blog.slimcode.com/2010/09/11/detect-when-a-listbox-scrolls-to-its-end-wp7/

Comment: thank you.. Interesting way to implement load more behavior.. I will check it :)

Answer (score 0):

Short version: You can't.

Long version: You can't, and I don't see why you would. The whole idea about having a **named** button that's inside a `ListBoxItem`, meaning it's rendered **several times**, doesn't make sense.

What you **really** want to do, is to bind the visibility to a property. Consider using a ValueConverter (Search for BoolToVisibilityConverter and thou shall find), so you can simply bind a boolean property from the item that's being databound.

Comment: The button in the question is not in the itme but the template of the whole ListBox. I would recommend the binding approach though

Comment: Hmmf, I thought I read ListBoxItem as TargetType in his code. Stupid eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this helper function:

```
        public static ChildItem FindVisualChild<ChildItem>(DependencyObject obj)
            where ChildItem : DependencyObject {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++) {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
                if (child != null && child is ChildItem) {
                    return (ChildItem)child;
                } else {
                    ChildItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<ChildItem>(child);
                    if (childOfChild != null) {
                        return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

To locate your button:

```
var button = FindVisualChild<Button>(listbox);
```